# C# com reference publish crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, com

I've never used C# before writing this app, and I loathe Visual Studio, so please bear with me if I am just being daft.

I've created a nice little utility that automates a number of painful processes at my job. I've presented it to a large number of people, including a number of people overseas who are keen to use it.

The only issue is... I cannot get the application to run on any machine besides my own. On any other machine, the application crashes immediately upon start.

I've positively ruled out any issues regarding .NET installation in the client machine by packing the application in an installer which installs the proper version of .NET if need be.

As of now, my thoughts are that I am handling packing my two COM references incorrectly or that the application is dying from a security exception.

The application utilizes the COM Excel reference as well as one other COM reference that any client running my app will have installed on their machine. I have attempted to both distribute the application relying on Visual Studio to work magic and pull needed references, and also to force the references to "CopyLocal". Isolating the references failed, but I'm not sure if that is necessary or not.

Does anyone have any clues as to what the issue could be? Don't hesitate to ask me for clarification on anything.

Comment: Additional details about the crash would be helpful. Is there an error message? What about in the details of the crash dialog?

Comment: No real error message on the crash. Simply an "application stopped working" message box. So there aren't any real details in it :/

Comment: You'll have to do a bit more work in your program so you don't just let it crash without a diagnostic.  Write an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event and display or log the value of e.UnhandledException.ToString().  It tells you why it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing some deploy problem. Even if it is true that copying the assembli and its used dll on the target machine typically work pretty well with .NET you are in a situation not exactly that simple.
First of all:

- nsure target machine have the .NET framework installed in a version compatible with the one you use for your program ( ie greather than or equal )
- ensure the proper COM objects are present and registered on the target machine. And this is the tricky part. 
  Since you are using excel, try to install on the target machine the [Primary interop assemblies ( PIA ) for office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx). This will probably solve your issue.

Comment: I have ensured that target machines have correct .NET frameworks already. VS provides an easy way to add a check and install if need be. I'm taking a look at the PIA assemblies now.

Comment: After reading the article you linked... I'm already using the Interop assemblies. I had already added the reference in the exact way specified, and a line from my code "using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;"

Comment: did you install the interop assemblies on the target machine as well? If I remember corectly there should be a redistributable